# Oauth SSO for REST applications

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am building a (set of) web application; the backend has REST-like API, the frontend will be some REST JS app, android apps etc; and I'm trying to come up with an SSO functionality.

Looking at Oauth2/OIDC it seems the best way would be to use Implicit flow; however, the access tokens in implicit flow (in oidc) have a set expiration. The refresh token is not part of implicit flow.

How do I ensure that the user will stay logged in? I.e. when the access token expires, the frontend application will try to obtain a new one from an auth server; that is supposed to ask for username/password. Alternatively, it can build a session with the frontend (using cookies), but how is that different from a refresh token?

It seems to me that getting the access token e.g. from the android app means at least opening the web browser; depending on the expiry length, that could be quite often. Is that the correct flow or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the issuance of a refresh token is not allowed with the Implicit grant type.
However, the refresh token and the access token are not needed to know if the user is logged in or not (the access token only allows you to access on protected resources). You have to use the ID Token which is issued in the authorization response.

You can verify if the user is still logged in by sending an authorization request with the query parameter `prompt=none` (see section [3.1.2.1.  Authentication Request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest)). I recommend you to send the current ID Token using the `id_token_hint` query parameter as mentioned in the same section:

> ID Token previously issued by the Authorization Server being passed as a hint about the End-User's current or past authenticated session with the Client. If the End-User identified by the ID Token is logged in or is logged in by the request, then the Authorization Server returns a positive response; otherwise, it SHOULD return an error, such as login_required. When possible, an id_token_hint SHOULD be present when prompt=none is used

If you receive an error (`login_required` or `interaction_required`) then the user may be logged out.

Another way could be to use the [Session Management](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) feature. But as this specification is not yet approved (draft 27), it may be subject to changes and may not be available. However it is a very simple way to know the status of the user.